# How to get available routes from the mux in go?

Tags: go, gorilla

I have a mux and 4 different routes.

```
a.Router = mux.NewRouter()

a.Router.HandleFunc("/1/query/{query}", a.sigQuery).Methods("GET")

a.Router.HandleFunc("/1/sis", a.rGet).Methods("GET")

a.Router.HandleFunc("/1/sigs", a.sigHandler).Methods("GET", "POST", "DELETE")

a.Router.HandleFunc("/1/nfeeds", a.nfeedGet).Methods("GET", "DELETE", "POST")
```

Is there a method where we can list the defined routes and get the  methods defined on them. I was trying this way: `routes := a.getRoutes()` will return me a slice with all the routes, and `methods := routes[1].Methods()` will return the methods listed on that route. Is there a way we can achieve this?

Comment: Which package is "mux"? I don't believe that's a standard library package, and there are a whole bunch of routers for Go out there.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker It's gorilla mux.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use the [`Walk`](http://www.gorillatoolkit.org/pkg/mux#Router.Walk) method:

```
router.Walk(func(route *mux.Route, router *mux.Router, ancestors []*mux.Route) error {
    tpl, err1 := route.GetPathTemplate()
    met, err2 := route.GetMethods()
    fmt.Println(tpl, err1, met, err2)
    return nil
})
```

Alternatively, you can just put all your routes into a slice of structs and just do

```
for _, r := range routes {
    router.HandleFunc(r.tpl, r.func).Methods(r.methods...)
}
```

on the initialisation step.